# MD5 checksum difference when using streams

Tags: md5, apache-commons

I try to generate MD5 checksum for a file, but somehow there is a problem with the way I am using it:

```
@Test
public void streamTestApacheCommonsCodec14() {
    String hash = null;
    try {

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\Work\\dataset\\main\\main.xml");
        BufferedInputStream entryBIS = new BufferedInputStream(is,
            Constants.BUFFER_MEDIUM);
        hash = DigestUtils.md5Hex(entryBIS);

        assertThat(hash,is(equalTo("9be6e92c6a8b684a35420cb087704a4c")));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail();
    }

}
```

***Passed***
If I use fileStream in the md5Hex parameter I still get a the *correct* checksum

```
 @Test
    public void fastMd5Twmacinta271() {
        String hash = null;
        try {
            hash = MD5.asHex(MD5.getHash(new File("C:\\Work\\dataset\\main\\main.xml")));
            assertThat(hash,is(equalTo("9be6e92c6a8b684a35420cb087704a4c")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail();
        }

    }
```

***Passed***

```
 @Test
    public void fastMd5TwmacintaStream271() {
        String hash = null;
        try {

            InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Work\\dataset\\main\\main.xml");
            BufferedInputStream entryBIS = new BufferedInputStream(fileStream,
                Constants.BUFFER_LARGE);

            com.twmacinta.util.MD5 md5Reader =  new com.twmacinta.util.MD5(entryBIS);
            hash = md5Reader.asHex();
            assertThat(hash,is(equalTo("9be6e92c6a8b684a35420cb087704a4c")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail();
        }
```

***Failed***
If I use fileStream in the constructor I still get a *wrong*, but *different* checksum

Does anybody know where is the problem? Is it a twmacinta bug?

Zoltan

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by not setting the character encoding to UTF8

Comment: But what did you do? (hi from EWII)